# Transition on img element cause size change or moving

Tags: html, css

I do opacity transition on img element as it is in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cKUFD/3/) and i see that img size changing or img is moving when transition on end or start;

Here is simple css code for styling.

```
img{
    height:165px;
    width:165px;
    opacity:0.4;
    transition: all linear 1s;
}

img:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

I tested it on Chrome 31 version. How can i get rid of this problem ?

Edit: This problem appears when Chrome browser is in bigger zoom like 110% or 125%

Comment: I am not seeing the image move when I hover over it in the example.  That is the problem correct?  I am in Chrome.

Comment: @stat30fbliss Yes, please check my comment on Danko answer.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be a bug in Chrome, just transitioning the opacity makes no difference for me.

Apply a 3D transform, of nothing, to resolve the issue.

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the movement but you can try with just the specific property instead of `all`:

```
transition: opacity linear 1s;
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/cKUFD/4/

Comment: Can you also test it before making chrome size bigger like 110% or 125% ? That is very tiny vibration or size change.

Comment: U mean zoom in? The window chrome?

Comment: @Freshblood I see a little jump at 110% .. Maybe It's a little conflict between the zoom and the fixed dimensions for img, when you remove the CSS width and height works well.

Comment: In my testing this doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem, so i tried different images in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s04428yc/15/

The first image works fine, while the second contracts on hover.
So i came to the conclusion that the image ratio is causing the problem.

And the solution was, like @addedlovely already stated:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

and this should be applied on the element without the hover pseudo selector.

Or one could simply change the actual image ratio.

Comment: Also in my particular case, Chrome over compensated by adding 1px to the image width (sometimes height). As i didnt mind losing that 1px from the img i added `overflow: hidden;` to the parent container to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a 1px transparent border to the right of the element fixed this for me. I had a grid of images with no space at all between them, and this bug would cause some of them to expand by 1 pixel horizontally when the transition happened.

`-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` does work, however, it also changed the width of some of the images by 1px permanently. (This fix *also* changes the width of the images by 1px permanently, but at least it's consistent.)

I ended up liking the look of a 1 pixel border more anyway and so I kept it, but this obviously won't be a fix for everyone because it changes the look of your page.